# Factors of $2^{3511-1}-1$, where $3511$ is a Wieferich prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

$\frac{3281273-715031}{2}$ divides $2^{3511-1}-1$, where $3511$ is a Wieferiech prime and $3281273$ and $715031$ are two Sophie Germain primes.

Factors of $2^{3511-1}-1$ are $73$,$31$,$3$ and $7$.

I noticed that the prime $3281273$, besides being a Sophie Germaine prime, is $\equiv 73*31*7*9*23$ $\pmod {1093}$. $1093$ is the other known Wieferich prime. Also the prime $715031$ besides being a Sofie Germain prime is $\equiv 9*5*7*31*73 \pmod  {1093}$ Is there any mathematical reason?

Comment: @GerryMeyerson is there any mathematical reason?

Comment: @Zvi primes $3281273$ and $715031$ occur in this other question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010097/1051-digit-primes